# How to call npm external command from Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to run an external command in Groovy. But I am getting:

> Caught: `java.io.IOException`: Cannot run program `npm install`:
> `CreateProcess error=2`, The system cannot find the file specified.

I am new to Groovy so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Also my path is set since I am able to run npm in command line.

```
def command = "npm install"
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()
println "This is output: " + proc?.err?.text
```

Comment: Is it windows or linux? If windows try `['cmd', '/c', 'npm', 'install'].execute()`.

Comment: windows, and it worked ! thanks for your help !

Comment: Also if linux, do we just switch cmd for bash ?

Comment: It depends if a command is shell built-in or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running on windows try:

```
['cmd', '/c', 'npm', 'install'].execute()
```

Also it's good practice to use `List.execute()` than `String.execute()`.